# Concatenation in Python, concatenating lists and strings

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

i'm not sure if this is the correct syntax to do this, but i want to print out a specific element in a list.

```
user,activity,data=readfile('data.txt')
kclust,clusters=kcluster(data,k=3)
for i in range(len(kclust)):
    print "Cluster %d: ??" % (i+1,clusters[i])
    print [[userobjectIds[r] for r in kclust[i]][:3]]
    print
```

the '??' is where i've tried %d and %o but get:
"TypeError:%o format:a number is required, not list"

Comment: Are you expecting to print a number?  You can verify that `clusters[i]` actually contains a number (or whatever type you intended) by reading the output of `print type(clusters[i])`.

Comment: Any time you're doing `for i in range(len(foo)):` you're probably doing it wrong. Do instead `for i, sublist in kclust.enumerate():` and the list comp can be `[userobjectIds[v] for v in sublist[:3]]`

Comment: @Daenyth: Should be `enumerate(kclust)` (unless `klust` is something different than a list). But this is definitely the correct approach.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Derp, brain fart. You're right of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You can use `%r`:](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

> 'r': String (converts any Python object using [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr)).

```
print "Cluster %d: %r" % (i+1,clusters[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about kcluster function, but it seems it returns a list, not a number. Alternatively, you could try:

```
print "Cluster %d:"%(i+1), clusters[i]
```